# Prove orthogonality of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $\alpha$ is unit vector, prove that $Q = I - 2 \alpha \alpha^{T} $ is orthogonal (aka $Q Q^{T} = I$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just compute $Q^2$ (as $Q=Q^T$). The only thing you might be missing is that $\alpha$ being a unit vector means that $\alpha^T\alpha=1$.